# VBA Macro for checking for common values and then summing their revenue

Tags: vba, excel

```
Vegetable               $ Amount              Farmer
Potato                    100                 John
Potato                    200                 Jack
Carrot                    50                  Paul
Carrot                    60                  John
Sweetcorn                 100                 Paul
```

I want to create a separate sheet in excel which will show how much each farmer has earned; how can I do this in VBA?
I have begun, but have become stuck.

```
Sub Demo()
Dim dict1 As Object
Dim c1 As Variant, k As Variant
Dim currWS As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, tot As Long
Dim number1 As Long, number2 As Long, firstRow As Long

Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("farmergoods")

'get last row withh data in Column A
lastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this without VBA, using a PivotTable or the SUMIFS formula.

However, with VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()

Dim currWS As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet
Dim Rin As Range, Rout As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
'Dim dict1 As Object ' late binding
Dim dict1 As New Scripting.Dictionary ' early binding and object creation, needs reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim key As Variant

'=== populate the dictionary with the input data ===

'Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' late binding
Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("farmergoods") ' set the input sheet
Set Rin = currWS.Range("A2") ' set the start of the input range
lastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row of input range (get last row with data in Column A)

Do While Rin.Row <= lastRow

    ' Column 3 ("C") is the farmer, column 2 ("B") is the $ amount
    If Not dict1.Exists(Rin(1, 3).Value) Then ' is the farmer NOT yet in the dictionary?
        dict1.Item(Rin(1, 3).Value) = Rin(1, 2).Value ' if the farmer is not yet in the dictionary, set the revenue value to the amount
    Else
        dict1.Item(Rin(1, 3).Value) = dict1.Item(Rin(1, 3).Value) + Rin(1, 2).Value  ' if the farmer is already in the dictionary, add the new amount to the previous revenue value
    End If

    Set Rin = Rin(2, 1) ' increment the input row
Loop

'=== populate the new worksheet with the dictionary items ===

Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ' set the output sheet
newWS.Name = "farmerrevenue"

' note: I'm creating a new worksheet here, if instead the worksheet already exists use:
'Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("farmerrevenue")

Set Rout = newWS.Range("A1") ' set the start of the output range

Rout.Resize(, 2).Value = Array("Farmer", "$ Revenue") ' add the header first

Set Rout = Rout(2, 1) ' increment the output row

For Each key In dict1.Keys

    Rout.Resize(, 2).Value = Array(key, dict1.Item(key)) ' write the (farmer, revenue) to the output range

    Set Rout = Rout(2, 1) ' increment the output row
Next key

Set dict1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, this is great. Although it only picks up distinct farmers, it has not covered the revenue where there is more than one farmer. Could you please advise?

Comment: I don't understand - that doesn't seem to be part of your question. Can you please update your question with a more indicative data set as well as the intended result?

Comment: Hi, Apologies was an error on my behalf, thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeHalford, happy to help. Does my answer resolve your question?